# Downloading byte[] file from a SQL Server Compact database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce

I have an ASP.NET MVC project with Entity Framework. My application accepts a file and saves it as `byte[]` in my SQL Server Compact database.

When I want to view the uploaded file, I want to transfer it to the normal file format. How is that possible?

This is my upload method

```
if (Request.Files != null && Request.Files.Count == 1)
{
    var file = Request.Files[0];

    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var content = new byte[file.ContentLength];
        file.InputStream.Read(content, 0, file.ContentLength);
        applicant.CV = content;

        db.Applicants.Add(applicant);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("list");
    }
}
```

I have multiple files and for each file I want to be able to download and see them upon clicking a button

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer it to the normal file format"? If you've uploaded the exact files then isn't it just a matter of saving those bytes to disk with the right file extension?

Comment: it means that i uploaded the file into a byte[] format in the database and i want to download it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply required converting bytes to characters

```
char[] chars = Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(da);
```

and return a file defining it's type and data to be included